# SQL Server 2005 inserting null when value hard coded

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc that creates an entery in a table.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_CaseDetails
        (
            Case_Id
            , Client_Id
            , Client_HO_Id
            , Client_Case_Ref
            , Client_Cust_Ref
            , Access_Id
            , Product_Id
            , Status
        )
        Values(

            @CaseId
            , @Client_Id
            , isnull(@Head_Office_Id,@Client_Id)
            , @Client_Case_Reference
            , @Client_Customer_Reference
            , @Access_Id
            , @Product_Id 
            , 'pre-instr')
```

But in the trigger the status is appearing as null and the insert fails as i have a check for a null status.

```
  If Update(Status)
        Begin
              If @Status Is Null
        Exec [usp_CaseWithNullStatus] @Case_Id
                 Begin
                       RaisError ( 'Cannot insert null status'
              ,16
              ,16 )
                 End
        End
```

Any ideas why this is happening?
Sp

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your inner begin / end block be set this way:

```
  If Update(Status)
  Begin
      If @Status Is Null
      Begin   -- <---------- block starts here
           Exec [usp_CaseWithNullStatus] @Case_Id
           RaisError ( 'Cannot insert null status'
              ,16
              ,16 )
      End
  End
```

In your code the raiserror will be *always* called, because the line following your if statement is considered as execution block and the next line will be called even if the if-statement isn't true.